# strange space in email template in Outlook

Tags: html, css, templates, outlook

I have created an email tempate.
Everything works fine in the browser.
But Outlook brings me a dash in with it.
In this one, the background just shines through the template.
Maybe someone has an idea in this regard?
Thanks in advance for your help!
greatings
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOHJr.png)

unfortunately i had to remove some code because of privacy and the 30000 limit

```
enter code here<body class="body" style="margin: auto">
<div width="100%" style="background-color: #d3d3d3; display: block;">
    <center>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class=" center w1" style="height: 1220px;">
            <tr>
                <td width="70px" style="background-color:#FFFFFF; height: 100%;">
                    <img height="100%" width="70px" class="spacer"
                        src="Linktransparent px"></img>
                </td>
                <center>
                    <td>
                        <table class="w2" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">
                            <tr>
                                
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="w2"
                                    style="height: 299px; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
                                    <!-- Feste höhe vergeben tr -->
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="height: 40px;">
                                            <img style="display: block;" width="100%" height="40px" class="spacer"
                                                src="http://1x1px_transparent.jpg"></img>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <!-- Feste höhe vergeben tr -->
                                    <tr style="height: 27px;">
                                        <td colspan="5" rowspan="1" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                                            <a href="h//wwe.com">
                                                <img height='23px' alt='.png'
                                                    src='http://link'></img>
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <!-- Feste höhe vergeben tr -->
                                    <tr style="height: 50px;">
                                        <td>
                                            <img height="50px" class="spacer"
                                                src="http://logo/1x1px_transparent.jpg"></img>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <!-- Feste höhe vergeben tr -->
                                    <tr class="dash_container" style="background:#f5f5f5; height: 2px !important;">
                                        <td class="dash" style="height: 2px">
                                            <img height="2px" class="spacer"
                                                src="x1px_transparent.jpg"></img>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <!-- Feste höhe vergeben tr -->
                                    <tr style="height: 60px;">
                                        <td><img height="60px" class="spacer"
                                                src="http://0/logo/1x1px_transparent.jpg"></img>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <!-- Feste höhe vergeben (vorvergeben bleibt stehen!!!) tr -->
                                    <tr style="height: 29px;">
                                        <td width="100%" class="text ft24M"
                                            style="font-size: 24px; font-weight: 500; font-family: 'Verdana'; text-align: center;">
                                            <span>Deine Rechnung</span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <!-- Feste höhe vergeben tr -->
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="height: 90px;">
                                            <img height="90px" class="spacer"
                                                src="http://f0/logo/1x1px_transparent.jpg"></img>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                
                                <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="w2"
                                    style="height: 48px;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <table class="w2 ">
                                                <tr class=" valignleft">
                                                    <td width="70" height="48px">
                                                        <img class="img"
                                                            src="http://ftp/Rechnungsdatum.png"></img>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td width="170" height="48px">
                                                        <table role="presentation" width="144" height="20"
                                                            cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td class="vbottom">
                                                                    <span class="text ft14M "
                                                                        style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: 500;">
                                                                        Bestelldatum
                                                                    </span>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td class="vtop">
                                                                    <span class="text ft14R "
                                                                        style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: 400;">
                                                                        XXbestelldXX
                                                                    </span>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td width="70">
                                                        <img class="img"
                                                            src="http://ftp.80/Bestellnummer.png"></img>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td width="170" height="48px">
                                                        <table role="presentation" width="135" height="20"
                                                            cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td class="vbottom">
                                                                    <span class="text ft14M "
                                                                        style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: 500;">
                                                                        Bestellnummer
                                                                    </span>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td class="vtop">
                                                                    <span class="text ft14R "
                                                                        style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: 400;">
                                                                        XXbnrXX
                                                                    </span>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td width="70" height="48px">
                                                        <img class="img"
                                                            src="http://ftp.80/Kundennummer.png"></img>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td width="135" height="48px">
                                                        <table role="presentation" width="135" height="20"
                                                            cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">

                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td class="vbottom">
                                                                    <span class="text ft14M "
                                                                        style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: 500;">
                                                                        Kundennummer
                                                                    </span>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td class="vtop; ">
                                                                    <span class="text ft14R "
                                                                        style="font-size: 14; font-weight: 400;">
                                                                        XXkunnrXX
                                                                    </span>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </td>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                               
                                <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="w2">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="height: 50px;">
                                            <img height="50px" class="spacer"
                                                src="http://ftplogo/1x1px_transparent.jpg"></img>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                
                                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
                                    style="height: 170px;  background-color: #FFFFFF;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <table role="presentation" class="w2 " border="0" cellspacing="0"
                                                cellpadding="0" style="background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 170px;">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td align="left" class="text ft14R "
                                                        style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: 400;">
                                                        <span>
                                                            <strong>XXanredXX,</strong><br />
                                                            <br />
                                                        </span>
                                                        <span>
                                                            anbei findest Du Deine Rechnung zur
                                                          
                                                            <a style="color: transparent;"
                                                                href="http://get.adobe.com/de/reader/"
                                                                target="_blank">
                                                                <strong><u style="color: black;">
                                                                        pdf-Reader</u></strong>
                                                            </a>
                                                            herunter.
                                                            <br>
                                                            <br>
                                                            Wir wünschen
                                                            <br />
                                                            <br>
                                                            Viele Gr&uuml;&szlig;e,
                                                        </span>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                
                                <table class="w2" role="presentation" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0"
                                    cellspacing="0" style="height: 96px; background-color: #FFFFFF;">
                                    <!-- Feste höhe vergeben tr -->
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="height: 70px;;">
                                            <img height="70px" class="spacer"
                                                src="http://ftpo/1x1px_transparent.jpg"></img>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="height: 27px;">
                                            <img height="27px" style="height: 27px;"
                                                src="http://ft/logo/1x1px_transparent.jpg"></img>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="text-align: right; height: 27px; width: 47px;" >
                                            <!-- Feste höhe vergeben tr -->

                                            <!--   <td align="center" colspan="5" rowspan="1" class="text ft16M"
                                            style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: 500; height: 27px; border: 0px;"> -->

                                            <div class="text ft16M  mar10R" >
                                                Dein
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        
                                        <td width="160px" height="27px">
                                            <div align="center" width="160px">
                                                <a class="trans_Logo" href="https.e.com">
                                                    <img style="vertical-align: middle;"  alt=inal.png'
                                                        src='http://ft0/logo_LOGO.png'></img>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        
                                        <td style="height: 27px; width: 53px;">
                                            <div class="text ft16M  mar10L" >
                                                Team
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="height: 27px;">
                                            <img height="27px" style="height: 27px;"
                                                src="//.jpg"></img>
                                        </td>
                                    <tr>
                                </table>
                                
                                <table class="w2" role="presentation" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
                                    style="height: 92px;">
                                    <!-- Feste höhe vergeben tr -->
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="height: 50px;">
                                            <img height="50px" class="spacer"
                                                src="htent.jpg"></img>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <!-- Feste höhe vergeben tr -->
                                    <tr class="dash_container" bgcolor="#f5f5f5"
                                        style="background:#f5f5f5; height: 2px !important;">
                                        <td class="dash" style="height: 2px;">
                                            <img height="2px" class="spacer"
                                                src="http://fent.jpg"></img>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <!-- Feste höhe vergeben tr -->
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="height: 40px;">
                                            <img height="40px" class="spacer"
                                                src="http://ftp0/nsparent.jpg"></img>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                
                                <table role="presentation" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
                                    style="height: 105px; ">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                <!-- Feste höhe vergeben tr -->
                                                <tr style="height: 46px;">
                                                    <td align="left" class="text ft14M "
                                                        style="font-size:14; font-weight: 500;">
                                                        <p>
                                                            <strong>Kontakt:</strong>
                                                        </p>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <!-- Feste höhe vergeben tr -->
                                                <tr style="height: 40px;">
                                                    <td align="left" class="text ft14R "
                                                        style="line-height: 20px;font-size: 14px; font-weight: 400;">
                                                        <span>
                                                            Sende uns eine Nachricht über das
                                                            <strong>Kontaktformular</strong>
                                                            oder
                                                            rufe
                                                            uns
                                                            an:<br />
                                                        </span>
                                                        <span>
                                                            <img src="http://ftpO/phone.png"
                                                                height="13">
                                                            0800 400 31 1* (Mo - Fr: 11:00-16:00 Uhr -
                                                            nicht an
                                                            dt.
                                                            Feiertagen).
                                                        </span>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <!-- Feste höhe vergeben tr -->
                                                <tr style="height: 20px;">
                                                    <td align="left" class="text ft12L "
                                                        style="line-height: 20px; font-size: 12px; font-weight: 300;">
                                                        <span>
                                                            * kostenfrei
                                                        </span>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                
                                <table class="w2" role="presentation" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
                                    style="height: 82px;">
                                    <!-- Feste höhe vergeben tr -->
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="height: 40px;">
                                            <img height="40px" class="spacer"
                                                src="http://ftpt.jpg"></img>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <!-- Feste höhe vergeben tr -->
                                    <tr class="dash_container" bgcolor="#f5f5f5"
                                        style="background:#f5f5f5; height: 2px !important;">
                                        <td class="dash" style="height: 2px;">
                                            <img height="2px" class="spacer"
                                                src="http://ftsparent.jpg"></img>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <!-- Feste höhe vergeben tr -->
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="height: 40px;">
                                            <img height="40px" class="spacer"
                                                src="http://jpg"></img>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                
                                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="height: 19px; ">
                                    <!-- Feste höhe vergeben tr -->
                                    <tr style="height: 20px;">
                                        <td align="left" class="text ft16M "
                                            style="font-weight: 500; font-size: 16px;">
                                            <span>
                                                Sichere Zahlarten</span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                
                                <table width="687" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="height: 61px;">
                                    <!-- Feste höhe vergeben tr -->
                                    <tr style="height: 61px;">
                                        <!-- Bei allen tds feste höhen vergeben -->
                                        <td width="72" style="height: 61px;">
                                            <img vspace="1" hspace="1"
                                                src="http://ftpng" height="20"
                                                width="62">
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="59" style="height: 61px;">
                                            <img vspace="1" hspace="1"
                                                src="http:/png" height="40"
                                                width="49">
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="114" style="height: 61px;">
                                            <img vspace="1" hspace="1"
                                                src="http://f080/PP-Logo.PNG" height="55"
                                                width="104">
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="114" VALIGN="Middl" Valign="left" style="height: 61px;">
                                            <img vspace="1" hspace="1"
                                                src="http://tive.png"
                                                height="18" width="104">
                                        </td>

                                        <td width="61" style="height: 61px;">
                                            <img vspace="1" hspace="1"
                                                src="http://ft-klarna.png"
                                                height="35" width="61">
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="132" style="height: 61px;">&nbsp</td>


                                        <td align="right" width="93px" style="height: 61px;">
                                            <img vspace="1" hspace="1"
                                                src="http://ftp.1.png" height="31"
                                                width="31">
                                        </td>

                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            
                    </td>
                </center>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </center>
</div>
```

Comment: Your description really isn't clear. Can you please expand on the issue and possibly provide screenshots and code so we can debug.

Comment: Please provide us some code. Otherwise we can't help you